# Creating an excel one-way data table in R -- Problem with my for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to create an excel one-way data table in R so that I can find the exponent that minimizes errors of a coefficient in an equation. I have a for loop that produces the correct result but it does something strange that I can't figure out.

Here is an example of the data. I'll use the Pythogrean Win formula from baseball and use a for loop to find the exponent that minimizes the mean absolute error in the win projections.

```
## Create Data

Teams <- c("Bulls", "Sharks", "Snakes", "Dogs", "Cats")
Wins <- c(5, 3, 8, 1, 9)
Losses <- 10 - Wins
Win.Pct <- Wins/(Wins + Losses)
Points.Gained <- c(30, 50, 44, 28, 60)
Points.Allowed <- c(28, 74, 40, 92, 25)
season <- data.frame(Teams, Wins, Losses, Win.Pct, Points.Gained, Points.Allowed)
season

## Calculate Scoring Ratio

season$Score.Ratio <- with(season, Points.Gained/Points.Allowed)

## Predict Wins from Scoring Ratio

exponent <- 2

season$Predicted.Wins <- season$Score.Ratio^exponent / (1 + season$Score.Ratio^exponent)

## Calculate Mean Absolute Error

season$Abs.Error <- with(season, abs(Win.Pct - Predicted.Wins))

mae <- mean(season$Abs.Error)
mae
```

Here is my for loop that is looking at a range of exponent options to see if any of them are better than the exponent, 2, used above. For some strange reason, when I run the for loop, it keeps repeating the table several times (many of the tables with incorrect results) until finally producing the correct table as the last one. Can anyone explain to me what is wrong with my for loop and why this is happening?

```
## Identify potential exponent options that minimize mean absolute error

exp.options <- seq(from = 0.5, to = 3, by = 0.1)
mae.results <- data.frame("Exp" = exp.options, "Results" = NA)

for(i in 1:length(exp.options)){
    win.pct <- season$Predicted.Wins
    pred.win.pct <- 
        (season$Points.Gained/season$Points.Allowed)^exp.options[i] / 
        (1 + (season$Points.Gained/season$Points.Allowed)^exp.options[i])

    mae.results[i,2] <- mean(abs(win.pct - pred.win.pct))
    print(mae.results) 
    }
```

Comment: Just move `print(mae.results)` outside the loop and I think you should be good to go.

Comment: `print()` inside the loop is printing each iteration, rather than just the final result.

Comment: Ah, that worked. I can't believe it was that simple!

Comment: Consider trying to move your work flow from a `for` loop to using `sapply` which is more natural in R. Instead of `for (i in 1:length(exp.options))`, you'd start with `sapply(exp.options, function(exponent) {_fill_in_here_})`. I see two advantages to this vs. `for` loop in your case: (1) you don't have to bother with populating the result element-by-element (this is handled for you) and (2) you can replace `exp.options[i]` with `exponent` (no `[i]`), which may "read" more naturally